In mysql 8, how do I do a derivated index on a TEXT column
I have a mysql table with a lot of long fields. One of them is an URL that can be very long (is type TEXT).
I had the issue
Cannot create a functional index on an expression that returns a BLOB or TEXT. Please consider using CAST.
I tried doing this:

create INDEX lowercase_url_index on users ( (CAST(LEFT(lower(url) ,
255) as CHAR(255))) ) USING BTREE;

But this index gets fully ignored when querying on the field in to lower
I tried creating an index on a text field to lower case but gets ignored

That index is pointless.  MySQL doesn't have any way to remember that your index should be used for lower case searches.  Have you considered creating a new column with that result, and searching that column?

@TimRoberts I should look into that. It feels dirty, like if it was the db job or at least an ORM job... but as said, it feels really dirty

You should use a case insensitive collatiin for your text column. Those usually have ci in their collation name.

There is no any reason for to store the URL in TEXT column even when it is very long. Use VARCHAR instead - it can store the values up to 64kb long which is enough in approximately all cases. And VARCHAR column can be indexeded freely. If your URL can be longer nevertheless then use TEXT column and an index by this column prefix (specify its length in the index definition - for example, CREATE INDEX ids ON table ( text_column(1024) )).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

assuming you have a table users with a column url of type TEXT, try:
-- Add a new column
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN lower_url VARCHAR(255);

-- Populate the new column
UPDATE users SET lower_url = LEFT(LOWER(url), 255);

-- Create an index on the new column
CREATE INDEX lower_url_index ON users (lower_url) USING BTREE;

-- Query using the new column
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower_url = LEFT(LOWER('https://example.com/some/very/long/url'), 255);


Even tho this felt dirty is what I went for, creating a new column and stuff
